# How to save output of cProfile.Profile() to a *.prof file in Python Script

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile, snakeviz

Hi I know the usage of command line method to profile a python script as given below.

`python -m cProfile -o program.prof my_program.py`

However I'm profiling specific piece of code in Python using cProfile module as given below.

```
import cProfile, pstats, io
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
# ... do something ...
pr.disable()
s = io.StringIO()
sortby = 'cumulative'
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortby)
ps.print_stats()
print(s.getvalue())
```

How do I save `pr` the output of `cProfile.Profile()` to a `*.profile` file instead of using `pstats.Stats()` to analyze and print the profiling results.
So I can use it to visually analyze the stats using SnakeViz or similar utilities.

Answer (score 14):

The Profile class has [a method to write the stats to a file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#profile.Profile.dump_stats). You can use this to save the output to a file.

```
filename = 'profile.prof'  # You can change this if needed
pr.dump_stats(filename)
```